# How to deploy Flask project on Plesk subdomain

Tags: wordpress, flask, plesk

I want to ask if there is a way to deploy my Flask project to a Plesk subdomain. The site is going to be created with wordpress inside Plesk. Also, i would like to have database support.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggeling with a similar issue. What i did was the following:

- Installed nginx
- In the subdomain -> Apache & nginx Settings, make sure to disable the proxy-mode under the nginx settings
- add the following to Additional nginx directives:

  ```
  location / {
      # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

      # Redefine the header fields that NGINX sends to the upstream server
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # Define the maximum file size on file uploads
      client_max_body_size 5M;
  }


  location /static/ {
      alias /var/www/vhosts/PATH/TO/FLASK/app/static/;
  }
  ```

The rest is handled by gunicorn, you can find a great tutorial here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, nginx has to be installed inside plesk? Also, how am i going to place the project on the subdomain?

Comment: yes, you can follow this instruction: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213944825-How-to-install-and-enable-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-a-Plesk-for-Linux-server

For placing it on a subdomain, simply create one via plesk and place your flask project in there.