# How to setup nginx for a Flask app on a server with Plesk installed

Tags: nginx, flask, config, plesk

I want to deploy a little Flask webapp on a root cloud server with Plesk installed. I  followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a) as it uses Nginx and Gunicorn, like proposed by the developer of Flask: Miguel Grinberg.

The problem is that Plesk has a modified variant of nginx pre-installed named sw-nginx and I've absolutely no clue on how to implement that line of code:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name my.subdomain.com;

    location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/my.subdomain.com/myproject/app.sock;
      }
}
```

If I just put in in a .conf file, the configtest of Nginx fails:

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/myproject.conf:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Maybe the syntax of the proxy_pass value is wrong (I tried many, here I put one of them), or maybe the proxy_pass param isn't supported or has to be implemented somewhere else?

PS: I also found this answer [How to deploy Flask project on Plesk subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677879/how-to-deploy-flask-project-on-plesk-subdomain?answertab=oldest#tab-top) 
But I read somewhere, that replacing sw-nginx by the standard nginx wouldn't be supported by Plesk. Don't want to break anything...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591098/2052575) may help.  You should be able to put that first codeblock directly in your config, as that's the contents of `/etc/nginx/proxy_params`, rather than the `include` line.  Perhaps try this and update?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your speedy comment. It worked!